# Reading the last line on vb.net label from Arduino serial monitor

Tags: vb.net, arduino, vb.net-2010, arduino-uno

I can't seem to transfer to label (vb.net) from the last line of the Arduino (connected to the coinslot). The arduino's output shows how much coin i've inserted into the coinslot. Then, i must transfer the last number in the output of arduino to the a label in my created vb.net program. The result is that the label shows all the line from the arduino output.  I'll post the codes and photos below.

[Here is the output from arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP6j9.png)

and

[Here is the label from my vb.net program (coins inserted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Lmu.jpg)

Here is the code in vb.net:

```
Private Sub printdoc_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Try
        For Each port As String In SerialPort.GetPortNames
            port = "COM8"
        Next
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = Val("9600")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        SerialPort1.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Label10.Text &= SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
End Sub
```

And Here is the code in arduino:

```
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

 volatile int coins = 0;

 void setup()
 {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode (2,INPUT_PULLUP);
   attachInterrupt(0, coinInserted, FALLING);
 }
 void coinInserted()
 {
   coins = coins + 1;
   Serial.println(coins); 
 }
```

Can't seem to find any solution for this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you not `String.Split` into a `String()` then select the last value?

Comment: First of all, I did not understand the first _For_ loop within **printdoc_Load**. It just rewrites _port_ as "COM8" for all values of _port_. Also are you making sure that Arduino UNO is always detected as "COM8"? Have you ever mentioned `SerialPort1.PortName` as "COM8"? Just to be sure, try to do a condition check After `SerialPort1.Open()` as `If SerialPort1.IsOpen() Then`